# Adding dictionaries together

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have two dictionaries and I'd like to be able to make them one:

Something like this pseudo-Python would be nice:

```
dic0 = {'dic0': 0}
dic1 = {'dic1': 1}

ndic = dic0 + dic1
# ndic would equal {'dic0': 0, 'dic1': 1}
```

Comment: @Sam Possible problem: {'dic0':0} + {'dic0':1}. What to do?

Comment: @palsch {'dic0':0} + {'dic0':1} should be equivalent to d={'dic0':0}; d.update({'dic0':1}) ?

Comment: Your syntax with the + operator is supported since Python 3.9, as per PEP 584

Answer (score 210, accepted):

If you're interested in creating a new dict without using intermediary storage: (this is faster, and in my opinion, cleaner than using `dict.items()`)

```
dic2 = dict(dic0, **dic1)
```

Or if you're happy to use one of the existing dicts:

```
dic0.update(dic1)
```

Comment: The first line fails if the keys are anything other than strings.

Comment: @BerryTsakala The problem with `+` is what happens in case of conflicts ? `.update()` is properly asymmetric.

Comment: You can make it terser by replacing 1st example with `dic2 = {dic0, **dic1}`

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks - Could either throw an exception (like `1/0` does) or just accept that it's asymmetric. Other implemented additions of non-numbers are already asymmetric - `[1] + [2]` is different from `[2] + [1]` and `'1' + '2'` is different from `'2' + '1'`.

Comment: @BerryTsakala you got your wish with python 3.9 :) But the operator is `|`, not `+`. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html

Answer (score 50):

Here are quite a few ways to add dictionaries.

You can use Python3's dictionary unpacking feature:

```
ndic = {**dic0, **dic1}
```

Note that in the case of duplicates, values from later arguments are used. This is also the case for the other examples listed here.

---

Or create a new dict by adding both items.

```
ndic = dict(tuple(dic0.items()) + tuple(dic1.items()))
```

---

If modifying `dic0` is OK:

```
dic0.update(dic1)
```

---

If modifying `dic0` is **NOT** OK:

```
ndic = dic0.copy()
ndic.update(dic1)
```

---

If all the keys in one dict are ensured to be strings (`dic1` in this case, of course args can be swapped)

```
ndic = dict(dic0, **dic1)
```

---

In some cases it may be handy to use dict comprehensions (Python 2.7 or newer),
Especially if you want to filter out or transform some keys/values at the same time.

```
ndic = {k: v for d in (dic0, dic1) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> dic0 = {'dic0':0}
>>> dic1 = {'dic1':1}
>>> ndic = dict(list(dic0.items()) + list(dic1.items()))
>>> ndic
{'dic0': 0, 'dic1': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: Note that the equivalent syntax for this in Python 3.x is `ndic = list(dict(dic0.items()) + list(dic1.items()))` since `.items()` not longer returns a list, but a (iterable)view

Comment: @BryceGuinta I assume you meant `ndic = dict(list(dic0.items()) + list(dic1.items()))`

Comment: @dimo414 Yes, my bad. I can't change it now however. I use [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) from `collections` to achieve this functionality now via `dict(ChainMap(dic1, dic0))`. However I have had to grab the source code from [the chainmap pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chainmap/1.0.2) for Python2.7. Notice how I switched the order of the dicts. In the Vijay's example the rightmost keys' values overwrite the leftmost while ChainMap gets it right and the leftmost keys' values have precedence over the right.

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for the [update method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

```
dic0.update( dic1 )
print( dic0 )
```

gives

```
{'dic0': 0, 'dic1': 1}
```

Comment: Nice, although it modifies dic0. I'm not sure if that is acceptable to the original poster.

Answer (score 7):

```
dic0.update(dic1)
```

Note this doesn't actually return the combined dictionary, it just mutates `dic0`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do it is to simply use your example code, but using the items() member of each dictionary. So, the code would be:

```
dic0 = {'dic0': 0}
dic1 = {'dic1': 1}
dic2 = dict(dic0.items() + dic1.items())
```

I tested this in IDLE and it works fine.
However, the previous question on this topic states that this method is slow and chews up memory. There are several other ways recommended there, so please see that if memory usage is important.

Comment: FYI, this creates a list of tuples, you'd need to run `dict(dic0.items() + dic1.items())`