# How to concatenate dicts in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dicts:

```
one: {
  'param': {
    'a': 1
  }
}

one: {
  'param': {
    'b': 1
  }
}
```

And I would like to concatenate both to create the `three`:

```
one: {
  'param': {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005066/adding-dictionaries-together-python

Comment: This is not valid Python, as such, it is ambiguous what you are trying to accomplish. Thankfully, Python is a programming language which are made to remove ambiguity. Use Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries of dictionaries merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga C'mon, Obvious copy-paste mistakes here from a 47 rep user.. Why not suggest an edit? Maybe you did..

Comment: The suggested edit is *still* not valid Python. *technically it is valid on Python 3.6 as a type annotation, but that is almost certainly not what was intended.

Comment: How many levels of nesting are these dicts supposed to have? It could be interpreted as either two or three.

Answer (score 2):

use `ChainMap` from collections module

```
from collections import ChainMap
...
d1 = dict(...)
d2 = dict(...)

chainmap1 = ChainMap(d1,d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
d1 = {'param': {'a': 1}}
d2 = {'param': {'b': 1}}
d1['param'].update(d2['param'])
```

Output:

```
{'param': {'b': 1, 'a': 1}}
```

Or, for a more generic solution:

```
def get_dict(d1, d2):
   return {a: dict(c.items()+d.items()) if all(not isinstance(h, dict) for _, h in c.items()) and all(not isinstance(h, dict) for _, h in d.items()) else get_dict(c, d) for (a, c), (_, d) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items())}

 print(get_dict({'param': {'a': 1}}, {'param': {'b': 1}}))
```

Output:

```
{'param': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}}
```

Comment: Nice. `update` is the way to go. My first thought was `append`.. But that wouldn't work would it?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. You need Python 3.5+.

```
one = {'param': {'a': 1}}
two = {'param': {'b': 1}}

three = {'param': {**one['param'], **two['param']}}

# {'param': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution will create a new dictionary preserving the old ones: `dict(first_dict.items() + second_dict.items())`

In your specific case:

```
three = {'param': dict(one['param'].items() + two['param'].items())}
```